# GCP can't write Biq query using by to_gbq

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Can't write Biq Query by following Error.

```
Python 3.5.6 
pandas-gbq 0.13.1 
google-cloud-bigquery 1.24.0
```

> ImportError: pandas-gbq requires google-cloud-bigquery: cannot import name 'TimeoutGuard'

code:

```
sample_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data_rows,columns['shop_name','category','nearest_station','telephone_number','address','DL_time'])
print(sample_dataframe)

sample_dataframe.to_gbq('NTT.aikidou2025', 'robotic-column-270803',if_exists = 'replace')
```

Comment: Try ` google-cloud-bigquery==1.22.0 ` instead

Comment: I tried that by !pip install google-cloud-bigquery==1.22.0 actually the error code was changed so this is a effective major, however GCP was still error 'ImportError: pandas-gbq requires google-cloud-bigquery >= 1.11.0, current version 1.10.0' so I changed the version of google-cloud-bigquery but GCP has still same error.

Comment: The problem is actually not solved, however !pip install google-cloud-bigquery==1.22.0
changed the error message so this problem is solved partially. For the reason why I think the measure is this command.

Answer (score 1):

While you did not post the packages you imported and installed in your environment, this error is generally related to missing required packages.

I was able to reproduce your case using ***Pandas*** and ***to_gbq*** method successfully without any error. For my attempt I used a Jupyter Notebook in a Cloud AI instance running Python 3.7.

First, I installed the following packages in my environment:

```
!pip install --upgrade google-bigquery[pandas] --quiet
!pip install --upgrade pandas_gbq
```

The second module (*pandas_gbq*) is necessary because it is not included in the ***google-bigquery[pandas]*** package, you can check the documentation [here](https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Subsequently, within the python script it's necessary to import *pandas* and *bigquery*. I also created a dummy dataframe in order to reproduce the case. As following:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery

records =[
    {
        "Name": "Alex",
        "Age": 25,
        "City":"New York"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Bryan",
        "Age": 27,
        "City":"San Francisco"

    }
]

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(
    records,columns=["Name","Age","City"])

print(dataframe)
```

And the output:

```
    Name  Age           City
0   Alex   25       New York
1  Bryan   27  San Francisco
```

Finally, I used the ***to_gbq*** method:

```
#to_gbq
dataframe.to_gbq('sample.pandas_bq_test',project_id="test-proj-261014",if_exists='append')
```

It was well executed and the data frame was in BigQuery. Therefore, I encourage you to check above if you properly installed all the packages I used. In addition, you can use `pip show <name_of_the_package>` to check whether it is installed and its version.

### Update

To use BigQuery and Pandas with DataLab, it is possible to use a virtual environment, read more about it [here](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/). So, it is assured all the necessary python dependencies are installed and no incompatibility is encountered.

I followed the following steps to run the above code in DataLab.

1. Create a DataLab instance and connection via *http://localhost:8081/*, following the *[documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstart)*.
2. Open a new notebook and select *Kernel* ***Python 3***

Run the below commands, where  is the name of your virtual environment.

```
!pip install virtualenv
!virtualenv <your-env>
!source <your-env>/bin/activate
!<your-env>/bin/pip install google-cloud-bigquery
```

Now you will be able to use *import pandas as pd* and *from google.cloud import bigquery*. I have tested with the code I provided above and it worked. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Thank you for your comment that was effective but still error code 'ImportError: pandas-gbq requires google-cloud-bigquery >= 1.11.0, current version 1.10.0' !pip list shows that version is 1.11.2 so I confused.

Comment: Did you run `!pip install --upgrade google-bigquery[pandas] ` and `!pip install --upgrade pandas_gbq`? What was the output , did any package was installed or upgraded ?

Comment: This is the out put.
google-bigquery 0.14 does not provide the extra 'pandas'
Successfully installed google-api-core-1.17.0 google-cloud-bigquery-1.24.0 google-cloud-core-1.3.0 google-resumable-media-0.5.0 googleapis-common-protos-1.51.0 pandas-gbq-0.13.1 pydata-google-auth-0.3.0 six-1.14.0

Comment: So it installed `google-bigquery[pandas]`, it does not have the pandas package. For this reason you have to use `!pip install --upgrade pandas_gbq` or `!pip install --upgrade pandas-gbq`. Is this second one successfully installed as well?

Comment: I confirmed !pip install --upgrade pandas-gbq is installed.

Comment: i run your code, the result is same error only deifference is I'm using datalab and Pytohn version is 3.5.6 may be it is a problem versions of Python.

Comment: Hello @西浦 直志, I have updated the answer with the instructions to use Pandas and Bigquery with DataLab. I have tested it and it works.

Comment: Thanks for my case !pip install google-cloud-bigquery==1.10.1 solved this error.

Comment: @西浦 直志, please, if you found this answer useful I would appreciate if you accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried !pip install google-cloud-bigquery==1.10.1 and this solved the error, it seems like proper for my Python version.